# set animation google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

well im trying to set the BOUNCE animation to a specific marker but whenever i call the `marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)` method console says "Cannot read property 'BOUNCE' of undefined" this means that marker is not defined right? but if I use marker.setTitle('Bouncing') the title does change. am i doing something wrong , here is the code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function addMarker(lat,lng,img,title,bounce)
        {
         var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: img,
            title: title,
            zIndex: 1
            });

            if(bounce=='set'){marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            marker.setTitle('Bouncing');};

        }
    </script>
```

php script

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($losDatos);$i++)
    {

    $utc=new DateTime($losDatos[$i]['fechaUtc']);
    $utc->modify('-'.horarioVerano().' hours');
    echo $utc->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if($losDatos[$i]['camion']==$camion)
    {
    $script.="addMarker(".$losDatos[$i]['latitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['longitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['img'].",".$losDatos[$i]['nombre'].",'set');";
    }else
    {
       $script.="addMarker(".$losDatos[$i]['latitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['longitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['img'].",".$losDatos[$i]['nombre'].");";
    }

    }

echo $script;
```

Comment: your code should work.  take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/rD8U6/

Comment: even if write the whole process in the console to execute it after , the same error is returned

Comment: @Gustavo can you post your entire code?

Comment: thats the entire code! :S i just call it according to some sql rows results

Comment: and u see the marker on the map right?

Comment: yes , i can see the marker but its not bouncing!

Comment: Your script tag is incorrectly formed. Should be: `<script type="text/javascript">`. That might help.

Comment: what are you doing w/ the php part of it? are you calling the php for the javascript?

Comment: @Drackir that was a finger mistake , in the script it is correctly formed.

Comment: @kjy112 i call the function addMarker for each row of data is that what you asked?

Comment: ok ive  figured out after a long time , the problem was that i was using the 3.2 version of the api , as soon as i removed the v=3.2 parameter the animation worked well.

Answer (score 12):

try:

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)
```

Comment: brother this method is not working with marker showing error.....?? will you elaborate your answer..Plz

Answer (score -1):

The way You specified it in you code is correct.

```
{
  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}
```

What you should check is if the marker is really referencing a marker object on the map.

OR

You can try setting the animation through marker options.

```
var markerOptions = {animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE}
```

or Try setting the animation without the `if(condition)` to to see if it bounces.

Also please check for equality this way in your `if` statement

```
if(bounce==="set"){ /*animate marker*/}
```

Answer (score -5):

The setAnimation param should be a string of either "BOUNCE" or "DROP".

marker.setAnimation("BOUNCE");

or

marker.setAnimation("DROP");

where marker is a google maps marker object:

Comment: You have to pass the enumeration provided by Google. Not just text.